# Serverless with input event triggers in Next.js

Tags: api, express, backend, next.js, serverless

I am new in serverless and I heard about the problem of cold start time.
I have an input value which trigger an api each time a user enter a new value and return suggestions.
The suggestions should be returned as soon as possible.
But with the problem of cold start time it can be a problem if the suggestions are returned after five seconds for example.
Thus, in my case is it recommended to avoid serverless function ?
If I need to avoid serverless in this case, is it possible to have in the same next.js app a serverless backend and a custom server backend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But with the problem of cold start time it can be a problem if the suggestions are returned after five seconds for example.

I think you have misunderstood cold starts, they will not create a system wide recurring delay once the function is invoked. It will happen initially and settle down.

In your case unless the api is hit rarely and suddenly faces a swarm of traffic, the issue would not occur.

> A cold start occurs when your function has no runtime instance available

In this case the function runtime itself will be instantiated for the first user.

The easiest way to solve this issue is by using a simple warming script, just setup a way for your endpoint to be hit on a schedule so it remains *warm* for user input.

Here is an example of setting it up on Lambda

https://www.sitepoint.com/create-aws-lambda-cron-job/

You can additionally beef up the solve by setting up a reverse proxy that cache's your results.